# is it possible to catch redis exceptions inside pipelined block?

Tags: ruby, redis

I am using redis gem with Ruby 1.9

Is it is possible to catch Redis exceptions inside Redis.pipelined to make sure the rest of the batch gets executed too?

I tried 
    redis.pipelined do
       begin
          redis.hGet ...
       rescue Redis::ComandError
          ...
       end
    end
but the `rescue` code never gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi seems to work similarly to pipelined except each operation is atomic.  My "aaa" key was set even tho the smembers caused an exception to be thrown.  I know this isn't exactly what you were looking for since u can't handle the exception inside the block.

```
#> $redis.multi do
*>   $redis.set "asdf", 1
*>   $redis.smembers "asdf"
*>   $redis.set "aaa", 2
*> end
```

Comment: thanks. I mean the exceptions raised by the redis driver when the pipelined commands are executed.

Comment: @akonsu updated answer, not exactly what you're looking for tho, but it does allow the rest of the statements to get executed.